# Extracting / Subsetting lists from huge dataframe in R

Tags: r, data.table, time-series, subset

I have a huge table with historic article demands. The list got around 2million rows for 150.000 different articles.

```
Actuals<- data.frame(Articel=c("A","A","B","B","n","n"), Date=c("2018-1-01","2018-1-02","2018-1-01","2018-1-02","2018-1-01","2018-1-02"),
                Quantity=c(33,42,21,25,77,88))
```

[Example Input Table Actuals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pTck.png)

For further processing, (ABC/XYZ-Analysis & Forecasting), I need Time Series of each Article in different lists.

[Output Subsetting Lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XOtQ.png)

In the past, I used the subsetting functions in a for loop for creating the time series lists

```
#Build Time series
groups<-unique(Actuals$Article)
Actuals_ts<- list ()
for (i in 1:length(groups)){
    name<-paste(i,groups[i],sep=': ')
    Actuals_ts[[name]]<-subset(Actuals,Actuals$ident==groups[i])}
```

In this case, with 150.000 Articles, this is not feasible anymore. Can you think of any work arrounds? Thank you in advance.

**Edit**
I also tried the split function:

```
`tic_start_split = Sys.time()
actuals_ts<-split(Actuals,with(Actuals,interaction(Actuals$ident)),drop = TRUE)
tic_end_split = Sys.time()

> tic_start_split
[1] "2018-03-13 12:59:20 CET"
> tic_end_split
[1] "2018-03-13 13:10:44 CET"`
```

The result is a large list with 1.8TB.

The actual split process took around 10 min:

But afterwards R loads the results for another 30 min. Is there a way to fasten it up?

Comment: Try : `Actuals_ts <- split(Actuals,Actuals$Article)` and then `names(Actuals_ts) <- paste(1:length(Actuals_ts),names(Actuals_ts),sep=': ')`

Comment: I applied the split function
 `actual_ts<-split(Actuals,with(Actuals,interaction(Actuals$Articel)),drop = TRUE)`




after a  couple of minutes the functions finshes (Red Stop Sign disapears) but I can't see any results and R doesnt execute any line of code anymore.

Comment: Actually it just finished. The result is a large list with 1.8TB.

The actual split process took around 10 min:

`tic_start_split = Sys.time()
actuals_ts<-split(Actuals,with(Actuals,interaction(Actuals$ident)),drop = TRUE)
tic_end_split = Sys.time()

> tic_start_split
[1] "2018-03-13 12:59:20 CET"
> tic_end_split
[1] "2018-03-13 13:10:44 CET"`


But afterwards R loads the results for another 30 min. Is there a way to fasten it up?

Comment: Wait, that's not possible. 2 million rows with 3 columns cannot become a list of 1.8 TB at most 1.8 GB...

Comment: Anyway, if you use data.table instead of data.frame, the split operation should be much faster

Comment: there are more than three columns: I just simplified it for the example. Currently there are six columns. I will review which of them are really needed, if it fastens up the process.

Comment: Why do you need to split the data into subsets?  If you use `data.table`, you can process subsets using something like `Actuals[, do_something(.SD), by = Article]`.